# jquery wrap (dynamic elements)

Tags: jquery

so I have been researching this all morning- and I'm pretty sure the code is correct but to explain I am trying to include a table in the dynamically generated input, so need the tr/td in there. I have reviewed the html/wrap/append etc. functions to no avail... :-(

See the comment there for the full script but really this is the meat of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried the wrap and document writes but it doesn't like it. what am I missing???

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input     fields we currently have
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input     field being added
        //http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/09/17/jquery-dynamically-adding-    form-elements/
        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum     value
        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' +     newNum).wrap('<td />');
        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name'     + newNum).val('');
        newElem.children(':second').attr('id', 'amt' + newNum).attr('name', 'amt'     + newNum).val('');
        newElem.children(':third').attr('id', 'value' + newNum).attr('name',     'value' + newNum).val('');
        newElem.children(':fourth').attr('id', 'test' + newNum).attr('name',     'test' + newNum).val('');
        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        document.write("<tr>");
        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
        document.write("</tr>");
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Take a look in the jQuery API on `prepend()` `append()` - I think this is way more comfortable than `document.write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `document.write()` in `$(document).ready()` will wipe out your existing document and start a new document.  I rather doubt that is what you intend (especially since you appear to be trying to add rows to an existing table).

You need to use jQuery functions for inserting new elements into the DOM instead of `document.write()`.  There are many jQuery calls for manipulating the DOM.  You can see some of them [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).  I'd guess that you want calls like [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).